# How would I be able to show my model field to my templates?

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to Django. Today, I decided not to follow any tutorials and whatnot to do my own site.

I have my `models.py` here which is

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
technology = models.CharField(max_length=100)
img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
site = models.URLField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "project"
    verbose_name_plural = "projects"
```

My `views.py`is

```
def works(request):
    work = Post.objects.all().order_by()
    context = {'work': work}
    return render(request, 'portfolio.html', context)
```

And the template is

```
<h3 class="text-center card-title title font-weight-bolder">{{how.do.i.put.it}}</h3>
```

Where do I get the words inside `{{here}}`?

I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Your model is called `portfolio` but you are retrieving a queryset from `post`?

Comment: @Reez0 Thank you! I just changed it to Portfolio.objects.all().order_by()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have model called Post? if so then try using this:

```
def works(request):
        works = Post.objects.all()
        context = {'works': works}
        return render(request, 'portfolio.html', context)
```

> Try this in template

```
{% for work in works %}
   <h3 class="text-center card-title title font-weight-bolder">{{work.title}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

> For the Image add this in project's url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
   ........
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

> In views.py add request.FILES to add  the image field

```
form = AddPortfolio(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
```

> In template  add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```

> And access the image in the template like this

```
{% for work in works %}
<img src = /media/{{work.img}} width="" height="">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it accessed a different view. What was posted was from a different model class

Comment: Do you have model called Post?

Comment: This worked def works(request):
        works = Portfolio.objects.all()
        context = {'works': works}
        return render(request, 'portfolio.html', context)

Comment: The only thing I need is to call the image

Comment: to show image try `<img src="/media/{{work.img}}">`

Comment: can you show me the code you tried for adding image ??

Comment: I tried <img src="{{work.img.url}}">, <img src="{{work.img.url}}">

Comment: show me your project's  urls.py and views.py for adding the portfolio model

Comment: urls.py from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('blog/', views.blog_index, name='blog-list'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', views.blog_detail, name='blog-detail'),
    path('works/', views.works, name='works')
]

Comment: @Highcenburg check the updated answer for adding and displaying the image

Comment: i already have the ones for the settings even before you posted those but thank you. I'm trying to access the images which is uploaded from the admin and to be posted on the template.

Comment: then where is your code to to display the image in your template

Comment: That's where I need help.

Answer (score 0):

return render(request, 'portfolio.html', context={"work":work})

Check if this works

{{ work }}

check whether you have model named post and whether you have registered it in admin and import it to views